# How to wait and populate the data accordingly in Bootstrap Vue?

Tags: javascript, twitter-bootstrap, vue.js, promise

I am using Bootstrap Vue Table. I am waiting for the data to be arrived and populate accordingly. And for getting and storing the data, I am using Vuex!

The problem I am facing is that the `<b-table>`'s provider function doesn't really wait for the data to be arrived and just displays the empty one immediately.

Here's my code:

```
<b-table class="table-lg fa-sort-icons table-rounded mt-3 mb-0" :items="fetchAllUsers" :fields="fields"></b-table>
```

Method:

```
fetchAllUsers(ctx) {

  this.$store.dispatch(types.GET_CREATED_USERS_ASYNC)

  return this.getAllUsers // this is a getter from vuex(mapGetter) which gets all the users
},
```

I used promises but that didn't really help:

```
let promise = new Promise((resolve, reject) => {
    if(Object.keys(this.getAllUsers).length > 0) {
        resolve(this.getAllUsers)
    } else {
        reject(this.getAllUsers)
    }
})

promise.then((data) => console.log(data))
```

Comment: use computed function so that it will rendor after getting.

Comment: @C2486 Let me try!